# The JTable.updateUI() doesn't refresh my table

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am trying to refresh my table panel when I click the LOAD button. The method replaceText() will be called the LOAD button in GUI is clicked. A new columnNames list and display content will be sent to update my tableModel which extends AbstractTableModel. Then table.updateUI() is called to refresh the table.

```
public class Table {
    private JPanel panel;
    private TableModel model;
    private JTable table;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;

    public Table(){
        this.panel = new JPanel();
        this.model = new TableModel();
        this.table = new JTable(model);
        this.scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    }

    public void replaceText(ArrayList<String> names, String[][] content){
        model.update(names, content);
        table.updateUI();
    }

    public JPanel build(){
        panel.setSize(1000, 300);
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.setVisible(true);

        return panel;
    }

}
```

And here is the code in my tableModel:

```
public class TableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    String[] colNames = new String[] {};
    String[][] content = new String[][] {};
    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return content.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return colNames.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return content[rowIndex][columnIndex];
    }

    public String getColumnName(int columIndex){
        return colNames[columIndex];
    }

    public void update(ArrayList<String> names, String[][] content){
        this.colNames = names.toArray(new String[0]);
        this.content = content;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class TableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
```

There is an interface called `TableModel`. Don't name the class the same as the interface. It is confusing.

```
table.updateUI();
```

You should NOT invoke updateUI(). That method is only used internally by Swing when you change the LAF. Changing the data is not changing the LAF.

It is the responsibility of the "model" to update the "view" when the data of the model is changed.

```
public void update(ArrayList<String> names, String[][] content){
    this.colNames = names.toArray(new String[0]);
    this.content = content;
}
```

Your update(…) method does NOT notify the view that the data has changed. This would be done by invoking the:

```
fireTableStructureChanged(…);
```

method of the AbstractTableModel in your update(…) method.

However, I see no reason to create a custom TableModel. I would suggest you just use the `DefaultTableModel`. It has a method `setDataVector(…)` that allows you to reset the data in the model.